# How do I delete availability tests after moving Applications Insights to another resource group?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I moved applications insights from one resource group to another one. After moving I still can see availability tests in AI although I didn´t mark them for the move. Now I can´t do anything with them - disable, delete, edit.

When I try to delete test I get notification that availability test was deleted. But it was not. When I try to disable it I get notification: Failed to update availabity test. Updating availability test "webtest-appservice" failed with error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ResourceNotFound",
        "message": "The Resource 'microsoft.insights/webtests/webtest-appservice-xxxxx-ain' under resource group 'xxx-rsg' was not found. For more details please go to https://aka.ms/ARMResourceNotFoundFix"
    }
}
```

Is there a way to delete them?

Comment: It's odd and I have an idea that you may move the application insights resource back to original resource group and try to move again. I haven't found any docs to describe your case. So why not spend some time and take a try?

Comment: Well,  I´ve tried to move it back and the other way several times. I've also tried it on several accounts or subscriptions. The same result.  I didn´t work. I think it is a bug. I haven´t try to delete tests using powershell because I´m not good at it.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use the [Web Tests - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/application-insights/webtests/delete) rest api.

On that page, there is a green button "Try it", just click it, and provide any necessary parameters.

Comment: Delete webtest using rest api doesn´t work. I´m getting response code 204 - No content. That is the odd thing about this. It´s look like tests don´t exist but I can see them. I will probably have to send a support request to microsoft.

Comment: Using the REST API worked for me to delete a CUSTOM marked Availability Test which I could not delete anymore in Azure Portal